# Stumped by MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table like this:

table_user_enrollments

```
username     role     class
John Doe     student  Algebra 1
Jane Duh     student  Algebra 1
Jeff Doh     student  Geometry
Jack Sprat   student  Algebra 1
Willie Winky student  Geometry
Donald Duck  teacher  Algebra 1
Mickey Mouse teacher  Geometry
```

And I want these results:

```
# of students   Class name  Teacher name
3                Algebra 1   Donald Duck
2                Geometry    Mickey Mouse
```

How would I go about writing the query?

```
(SELECT COUNT ue.username
FROM user_enrollments AS ue
WHERE ue.role="student") AS "# of Students",
ue.class AS "Class name",
(SELECT ue.username
FROM user_enrollments AS ue
WHERE ue.role="teacher") AS "Teacher name"
```

The query above doesn't work, of course, but I'm not sure what approach to take.

The table above is greatly simplified. In my real life example, the table is the result of 8 joins. This is closer to my real query:

```
(SELECT COUNT u.username
WHERE ra.roleid='5') AS "Number of Students",
c.fullname AS "Course name",
(SELECT u.username
WHERE ra.roleid='3') AS "Teacher name"

FROM prefix_user u
JOIN prefix_user_enrolments ue on ue.userid=u.id
JOIN prefix_enrol e ON e.id=ue.enrolid
JOIN prefix_course c on c.id = e.courseid
JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON ctx.instanceid = c.id
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN prefix_role AS r ON r.id = e.roleid
JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id=c.category

WHERE ra.userid=u.id

GROUP BY c.id
```

I know the subqueries won't work as they are written, but i don't know how to write them correctly, and I've included the WHERE clauses so you get the gist of what I need.

I also know it may seem like I'm joining unnecessary tables, but some of them are necessary as a bridge to join two tables that don't share a common column.

Thanks for the help!
Kimber

Comment: I'd really love it if Donald Duck taught me Algebra

Comment: Sometimes a simpler solution presents itself from the more complex: what's the structure of your actual table(s)? Going on that would also save you the possibility of forming a working query only to have it not work on the real table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  teachers.username,
  teachers.class,
  count(*) as nr_of_students
from
  user_enrollments teachers
inner join user_enrollments students on 
    teachers.role = 'teacher' and
    students.role = 'student' and
    teachers.class = students.class
group by 
  teachers.username,
  teachers.class
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ff3d1/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: This is terrific! I didn't know that tables could be joined by specific values like INNER JOIN ON teachers.role='teacher' and students.role='student'. I've only seen joins like teachers.class=students.class. If you wouldn't mind explaining, what happens in the join statements you used? I can see that it works, but I don't understand WHY it works.  I especially appreciated the inclusion of the link to sqlfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Well, actually you could put `teachers.role = 'teacher' and
    students.role = 'student'` into the `where` clause as well. I just got used to putting logic where it belongs. Sometimes it's also necessary to have those in the join condition, for example when you `left join`. Having filters like above in the `where` clause would actually make the `left join` an `inner join`. That's why I got used to it. Here's a good explanation about joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select class as [Class Name], username as [Teacher Name],
(
    select count(username)
    from table_user_enrollments
    where role = 'student'
    and class = e.class
) as [No of Student]
from table_user_enrollments e
where role = 'teacher'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you're looking for:

```
select 
    count(t1.username) as "# of students",
    t1.class as "class name",
    t2.username as "Teacher name"
from
    table_user_enrollments t1
       left join
    table_user_enrollments t2 
on
    t1.class = t2.class
where t1.role = 'student' 
and t2.role = 'teacher'
group by t1.class
```